# How to interpret individual random intercepts in mixed effects ordinal regression (clmm)?

Tags: r, regression, random-effects-model, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I am fitting the following ordinal regression with the `clmm` function in the `R ordinal` package.

```
mdl <- clmm(ordDV ~ IV + (1+IV|subject), data = MO)
randeff <- ranef(mdl)
```

ordDV is an ordinal variable with values 0,1,2 and 3.

From what I understand, in ordinal logistic regression there are generally j-1 intercepts (j = # of categories of DV). And each intercept represents the expected odds of being in that category or less than that category vs. a category greater than that.

Now, the `randeff` variable that I've extracted from my model contains a two column matrix with my random intercept and random slope. I'm struggling to understand what each individual random intercept means. It looks like some kind of a deviation, since it's distributed around 0.
But then what is it a deviation from?

Following my understanding of main intercepts, shouldn't there also be j-1 different random intercepts for every level of my grouping variable `subject`?

So, say the random intercept of subject 1 is -0.74, what does this mean? Does it mean that the odds to get a lower level response is are higher than a higher level one? I have seen a couple of questions regarding coefficient interpretation in `clmm` but this unfortunately didn't really help..